# How to authenticate requests using ServiceStack, own user repository, and device ids?

Tags: servicestack

I'm building a mobile app and a ServiceStack web service back-end. The Authentication stuff in ServiceStack looks great but easy to get lost in its flexibility - guidance much appreciated. I'll be using my own db tables for storing users etc within the web service. I'd like to have a registration process and subsequent authentication something like this:

- the user initially provides just an email address, my web service then emails a registration key to the user
- the user enters the key. The app sends to the web service for registration: email, key & a unique device identifier.
- the web service verifies the key and stores the email & device id. It responds back with an auth token that the app will use for later authentication.

Then subsequent web service requests would provide the device id and auth token (or a hash created with it). The app is not very chatty so I'm tempted to send the authentication details on each web request.

**Question 1**: Should I hook into ServiceStack's registration API or just add a couple of custom web service calls? e.g. without using ServiceStack's registration I would:

- post to a registration web service with the email address and device id. My web service would send the registration email with a key and add a record to the user db table.
- when the user enters the key it would again post to the registration web service,  this time also with the key. My web service would validate the key and update the user table marking the user as registered, creating and recording the auth token & returning it to the caller
- subsequent requests would be sent using http basic auth with the device id as username and the auth token as password. The service is not very chatty so creds will be sent with each request.
- I'll implement a CredentialsAuthProvider that'll get the creds with httpRequest.GetBasicAuthUserAndPassword() and validate them against the db data.

But it feels like I should use registration built in to ServiceStack.

**Question 2**: What's wrong with passing the authentication details with each request? This would make it easier for composing my app requests but it doesn't seem 'done' based on the ServiceStack examples. Presumably that's because it's inefficient if you have lots of requests to need to re-authenticate every call - any other reasons? My app will only make a single web request at most every few minutes so it seems simpler to avoid having sessions and just re-auth each request.

**Question 3**: Am I on the right track subclassing CredentialsAuthProvider?

**Question 4**: Is there any point using the auth token to generate a hash instead of sending the auth token each time? All communication will be over https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer1:**  It will be OK. if you give multiple call as per requirement. Normally authentication works based on cookie, now you can store it on client and/or on server and match the user with it. Again here if you are using device you, can always use device instead of user to map and authenticate user. Based on your requirement.

I will prefer to use provider as it hides many details which you need to do manually instead. You are on right track. There are many blogs specifically for authentication and how to create custom authentication with service stack. If you like let me know I have book marked some will give it you. Best way to search latest one is checkout twitter account of Servicestack.

**Answer2:** This is again, I say as per requirement. Now if your user will be in WIFI zone only. (Mostly true for business users), then there is not limit for calls. Just give a API call and do the authentication in background. Simple JSON token will not hurt, It is few bytes only. But again if you have big user base who is not using good internet connection then it will be better to store authentication detail on device and check against that. Just to save a network call. In any case network call is resource heavy.

**Answer3:** Yes you are on a right track. Still check out blog entries for more details. I don't remember the code snippet and how it works with last update so I am not putting up code here.

**Answer4:** This is answer is little complicated. Passing data over https and saving user from Identity fraud is little different thing. Now, if you are not generating auth token (hash based value) then you can pass user also over the http or https. Now, this can be used by another user to mock first user and send data. Even data is being passed through https but still data is getting mocked. Hashed based value is used to avoid this situation. And also there are couple of other business use cases can be covered using auth token.

Please let me know if I have understand you questions correctly and answered them?? or If any further details is required??